# PHP Session variables writing over one another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, variables

Ok, so I write my

```
$_GET['page_username']
```

variable into a

```
$_SESSION['page_username']
```

variable (after I validate it), and I have an ajax function that makes a database connection based on the session variable.

The problem I have is that when I open a new tab in the browser, and browse to a different user's page, the variable is overwritten, and my button that triggers the ajax request defaults to that of the recently opened page.

I understand why this is, and I am looking for a creative workaround.

I have thought about making each page have a unique session array, such as

```
$_SESSION['someuser']['user_id']
```

and using javascript parsing the username from the url to pass the ajax request.

The session array method would be fairly safe, as the variable is only used to access session array values, but I am curious if there are other options.

Comment: Why do you need to save the user being viewed in a session?

Comment: I wanted to because it was easier to pass variables internally in my ajax requests, but now it seems I'll have to resort to either a unique session array, or another method.

Comment: Could you just keep it as a `$_GET` parameter?

Comment: You can't access $_GET parameters through an ajax request file.  Unless you send the $_GET as a string.

Comment: Does it help if you first check if the session variable exists and write it only if it doesn't?

Comment: No because it's about a session variable in another tab overwriting another session variable.  I think the best way might be to just create a unique session variable, such as $_SESSION['someuser']['user_id'], and use javascript to access the session variable... That way I can verify the variable with isset(). It seems to be the most secure approach I can think up.  Open for other ideas though.

Comment: `and use javascript to access the session variable... It seems to be the most secure approach I can think up` Good one. I would suggest you tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish so we can give you better advice.

Comment: Well, I made the mistake of creating a user page, and setting most of the variables on the page as session variables.  I did this because I have a "follow" option, and when the user presses the follow button, it uses one of the session variables in the request.  The problem I ran into is when I open a new tab, and browse to a different user's page, the session variable is overwritten.  Then, when I switch to the other window and make the request, it defaults to the most recent (wrong) session variable.

Comment: The site's still in dev, so it's no biggie, and I think multisession arrays should fix it, I just love hearing other methods.

Comment: How about saving the user ID on each page inside the `DOM`, which then you access using javascript or any other client script, to send via AJAX to PHP?

Comment: I am not sure if it's safe to have user ids in my html.. I read something about that being dangerous.  It's not a bad idea though really, and the validation would be easier.  Maybe if the user id was written dynamically into the dom via ajax, then there'd be no hard coded version people could peek at.  I could put a request near the header so it loaded with the page.

Comment: This is how it's done, basically. Everything you put on the client side is untrustworthy so you have to do a very good normalization and validation if you're considered about security, which would still be easier and simpler than setting up a whole server-side-only data passing system, which I don't even know if is possible, and may turn out insecure as well, since sessions infact **are** 'jackable'

Comment: What I ended up doing was parsing the username from the url via javascript, and then sending it to php (ajax) to verify it's a valid username, then I check if the username session variable exists.  So in other words, I use javascript only to verify a set of session variables (in a named array such as $_SESSION['someuser']['userinfo']) ,so there's no direct connection to the db through the javascript variable.  I need to read up on php session hijacking.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you considered doing `$_SESSION[$userID] = array('someAttribute' => 'someValue);` ?